# Angular 11 open select when clicked on arrow icon next to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to open select field when user clicks arrow icon next it. I have developed the select filed with arrow icon like below code snippet. as per my needs I need to show down arrow on close state, up arrow on open state. I have achieved that using CSS.

When user clicks on exactly on the icon, nothing happening but It should behave like clicking on the select field. I have tried many ways but not able to get any solution.

Can you please help me, I really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

I have also created the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-new-8gjacv?file=src/app/app.component.html).

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-5">
      <select
        class="form-control form-select"
        id="ch"
        name="select-option"
        (focusout)="downIcon()"
        (click)="toggleIcon()"
        (change)="changeDropDown($event)"
      >
        <option value="option1">Option1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option4</option>
      </select>
      <span class="align">
        <em class="arrow" id="icon"></em>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have a caret outside `<select>`, `(click)` and other events are not fired when clicking caret.

If you can accept another caret style, I have forked [a sample stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-new-cuejvq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) from your sample. Please see it.